# Data tweaking code runs fine when executed directly - but never stops when used in trigger

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have written some code to ensure that items on an order are all numbered (*the "position number" or "item number" has been introduced only recently and we did not want to go and change all related code - as it is "asthetics only" and has no functional impact.*)

So, the idea is to go and check for an records that jave an itemno of NULL or 0 - and then compute one and assign it. When executing this code in a query window, it works fine. When putting it into an AFTER INSERT-trigger, it loops forever.

So what is wrong here?

```
/****** Objekt:  Trigger [SetzePosNr]    Skriptdatum: 02/28/2010 20:06:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [SetzePosNr]
ON [dbo].[bestellpos]
   AFTER INSERT 
  AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @idb int
   DECLARE @idp int
   DECLARE @pnr int

   SELECT @idp=id,@idb=id_bestellungen FROM bestellpos WHERE posnr IS NULL OR posnr=0

   WHILE @idp IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN   
      SELECT @pnr = 1+max(posnr) FROM bestellpos WHERE id_bestellungen = @idb
print( 'idp=' + str(@idp) + ', idb=' + str(@idb) + ', posnr=' + str(@pnr))
      UPDATE bestellpos SET posnr=@pnr WHERE id=@idp
      SELECT @idp=id,@idb=id_bestellungen FROM bestellpos WHERE posnr IS NULL OR posnr=0
   END
 END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaargh - just found the problem: the 3d line (from the end, the SELECT-statement) does not assign the variables when there result of the WHERE is NULL. So "set @idp=null" before that statement has fixed the problem! 
Not sure whhy I assumed a problem between direct execution and triggering of these statements, seems I picked the wrong test-cases :(